# Need help to decipher this encrypted text

Tags: cipher, puzzle-identification

I am relatively new to deciphering texts and I have the following ciphertext:

> xbt ufp ekyzkikn dt nkojvhk? e ndmr jfo nggv du kwjt gun pjv.

I tried Caesar Cipher but to no avail.

It would be helpful if you could explain the steps leading to the solution.

Comment: Where did you get the message from? Do you have any context? Perhaps some flavour text that happens to mention Cindy and the number seven? (Yes, I know what the plain text is, but it was more a lucky shot in the dark than any structured effort at decoding.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a

> [vigenere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) cipher with key “vbgwr” (odd key)

The message is

> can you decipher my message? i will not make it easy for you

How I found the key

> Well, I... kind of cheated. There’s a Vigenere solver online here: https://www.guballa.de/vigenere-solver

Comment: How did you find the key?

Comment: For what it's worth, the key is "Cindy" Caesar-shifted by seven places. I have no idea how this could relate to the hint "born with it".